# popup tip without JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a site where there is some authentication that is triggering a popup like the image below. I have deleted all the JS and CSS using firebug and it still triggers the popup. Has anyone used a popup like this and how is it being generated so I can stop it.

I can't give out the link to the site so I know its hard for people to answer without the code but I'm hoping someone has implemented something like this popup and can put me in the right direction.

I feel like its a ghost popup right now :)

[image]

Comment: I think you _cannot_ have deleted all the CSS & JavaScript if that is still appearing.

Comment: I thought if you delete it in firebug it should not technically not work. Ok I'll try removing it from the files directly then. Thanks for clearing that up. So why the option in firebug to delete elements then.

Comment: Once the script fires it loads itself into memory. Deleting the script from DOM does nothing (I only guess that this is what you are trying to do - I am Chrome user, I don't even know how firebug works :] ), because the script is already in the part of the memory which is unrelated to DOM. And you're right: deleting scripts from DOM is absolutely pointless in most cases. I guess that deleting elements was intented to use with other elements. Although to be honest, I've never used it even once. :) Although if it is HTML5 (as other suggest) then it is different story.

Comment: Thanks freakish for the explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is HTML5's validation. If you specified attribute `type` as `email`, HTML5 compliant browsers will validate the input as an email address.

You can turn these off by including attribute `novalidate` in your `form` tag, like so:

```
<form id="beh" novalidate>
```

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-novalidate

Comment: I actual don't want to turn it off I just want to style the popup and reposition it. I can't get my hands on the css because every timeI try to click on the popup to see the css in firebug it disappears.

Comment: It is not possible to style this with HTML nor with CSS, it is part of the browser. Additionally, this popup will only display in HTML5 browsers - I would recommend using your own validation with custom elements.

Comment: So is this feature turned on by default because I have never seen it before.

Comment: It is a part of HTML5. It will not display in earlier browsers, and is enabled by default in HTML5 browsers.

Answer (score 2):

If it's doing it without any js/css it's using HTML5's input validation.

Comment: Where would I find the html validation? Would it be directly in the html on the page? Also is it possible to trigger a default popup like this in JS